# Android Room data modeling with embedded FKs

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to represent the following entities:

- `Warning`: A warning entity with a unique id, title, subtitle, and up to 6 actions (below)
- `Action`: An action entity with a unique id, text, icon, etc. relevant to zero or more warnings

Examples of this relationship would be:

- *Missile Lock* warning with actions *Evasive Maneuver*, *Release Chaff*, and *Deploy Flare*.
- *Incoming gunfire* warning with actions *Evasive Maneuver*, *Return Fire*, and *GTFO*

Here's what I have:

**The `Warning` entity**

```
@Entity(tableName = WARNING_TABLE, 
        indices = [Index(unique = true, value = [WARNING_TITLE, WARNING_SUBTITILE])]
       )
data class Warning(
        @field:PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = WARNING_ID) var id: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = WARNING_TITLE) var text1: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = WARNING_SUBTITILE) var text2: String?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = WARNING_ACTIVE, defaultValue = "0") var active: Boolean = false
)
```

**The `Action` entity**

```
@Entity(tableName = ACTION_TABLE, 
        indices = [
                    Index(unique = true, value = [ACTION_TEXT]), 
                    Index(unique = true, value = [ACTION_ICON])
                  ]
        )
data class Action(
        @field:PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = ACTION_ID) var id: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = ACTION_TEXT) var text: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = ACTION_ICON) var icon: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = ACTION_ICON_SRC, defaultValue = "$DRAWABLE_SOURCE_RESOURCES") var iconSrc: DrawableSource? = DrawableSource.Resources
)
```

... and the table that links the two, the `warning_action` table:

```
@Entity(tableName = WARNING_ACTION_TABLE,
        primaryKeys = [WARNING_ID, ACTION_ID],
        foreignKeys = [
                        ForeignKey(entity = Warning::class,
                                   parentColumns = [WARNING_ID],
                                   childColumns = [WARNING_ID],
                                   onUpdate = ForeignKey.NO_ACTION,
                                   onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE),
                        ForeignKey(entity = Action::class,
                                   parentColumns = [ACTION_ID],
                                   childColumns = [ACTION_ID],
                                   onUpdate = ForeignKey.NO_ACTION,
                                   onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)
                      ],
        indices = [Index(ACTION_ID), Index(WARNING_ID)]
)
data class WarningAction(@ColumnInfo(name = ACTION_ID) val action: String,
                               @ColumnInfo(name = WARNING_ID) val warning: String)
```

Now what I want to do is to be able to load a list of all Warnings and their associated Actions (or a Single warning and its associated actions).

This is what I have so far, but it isn't working:

```
data class WarningWithActions(@Embedded val warning: Warning,
                              @Relation(parentColumn = WARNING_ID,
                                        entityColumn = ACTION_ID,
                                        associateBy = Junction(WarningAction::class))
                              val actions: List<Action>){
    val id get() = Warning.id
}
```

... and in the DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM '$WARNING_TABLE' WHERE $WARNING_ID = :id")
fun load (id:String): Maybe<WarningWithActions>
```

I also tried:

```
data class WarningWithActions(@Embedded val warning: Warning,
                                    @Relation(parentColumn = WARNING_ID,
                                        entity= Action::class,
                                        entityColumn = ACTION_ID,
                                        associateBy = Junction(value = WarningAction::class, parentColumn = WARNING_ID, entityColumn = ACTION_ID))
                                    val actions: List<Action>){
    val id get() = warning.id
}
```

I get an empty list of actions and I'm pretty sure I'm missing something that tells room how to get those, but I can't figure out what I'm missing here.

I've already used *Database Inspector* and verified that the actions exist, the warnings exist, and the link entries in the link table also exist.

**UPDATE:**

Turns out the above implementation is correct. The DAO method that was adding the action to the warning had a `Single<Long>` (RX) return value:

```
@Transaction
@Query ("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO '$WARNING_ACTION_TABLE' ($WARNING_ID, $ACTION_ID) VALUES (:wid, :aid)")
fun addAction (eid:String, aid:String):Single<Long>
```

I guess at some point while writing the unit test that tested this, I was distracted and forgot to `subscribe()`

Comment: It seems you've done it right, according to documentation. I just can propose to double-check your data (try logcat to check all data in tables in realtime instead of database inspector),or to use usual magic (invalidate cache, uninstall app, change room's version and so on).

Comment: @sergiytikhonov Thank you. Turns out I _had_ done it correctly. The DAO method that was adding the action to the warning had a `Single<Long>` return value ... I guess at some point while writing the unit test that tested this, I was distracted and forgot to `subscribe()`.